# JQuery Easing and WebPack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have a button that have to hide a frameset and show the following one

This a part of my HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/scripts-bundled.js"></script>
```

This is where the easing function is called

```
import $ from "jquery";

class FormController {
  // variables declararations and some code not useful now...

  buttonClicked(evt) {

    this.current_object.animate(
      { opacity: 0 },
      {
        step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = now * 50 + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        this.current_object.css({
          transform: "scale(" + scale + ")",
          position: "absolute"
        });
        this.next_object.css({ left: left, opacity: opacity });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        this.current_object.hide();
        this.animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: "easeInOutBack"
    }
  );
}
```

If I run this code and I click on the button I receive this error
**Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function**

I believe that, for some reason, the easing plugin is not loaded properly.

Is there a way to require it inside the code via Webpack?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with jquery.easing and then fix it via Webpack this way:

Add these dependencies to `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16"
}
```

`npm run install` to install dependencies and import it in your `main.js` file:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
    require('jquery.easing'); // dat works :3
} catch (e) {}
```

Then run webpack script (like `npm run dev`) to make a build for the application.
That's works fine for me.

Comment: I will try! Thanks for now

Answer (score 0):

install jquery.easing,

and for importing to your main.js file just import as:
import "jquery.easing";